# How to authorized azure rest api for resource health check

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I tried to get azure resource health check via rest api. Following link is used [Availability Statuses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resourcehealth/availabilitystatuses/getbyresource).
But i don't know how to get the authorization keys for azure api.(always getting unauthorised message).I m calling this rest api from my c# application.Is there any step to get permanent authorisation token creation for calling azure rest API for resource health check

Comment: does my answer work for you? Do you need any additional help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Service Principal, store the secrets securely, and use it to acquire token. Then you can just use this token in Azure REST API.

Watch this 2min video: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#how-to-call-azure-rest-apis-with-postman

Or read this: https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/azure-rest-apis-postman/